# How do you return all documents with a value for a field in mongo?

Tags: mongodb

I want to return all documents in mongo that have a value for a field. For instance, I want to return all documents where name is not null:

```
db.people.find({name: "not null"})
```

How do I do this in Mongo DB?

Comment: Did you try the [**`$ne`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/#ne) operator `db.people.find({name: {$ne:null}});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$ne` with `null`

```
db.people.find({name: {$ne: null}})
```

`$exists` will still find a record where `name` is actually `null`.